# Integrate a CollectionView in an ItemView with marionette

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have an app which displays rooms, and for each room it displays reservations for this room.

So, I have:

- My App (**BtApp**)

  - A **RoomsCollectionView** which displays RoomView ItemsViews (from a RoomsCollection)
  - Several **RoomView** which displays Room informations

    - A **ReservationsCollectionView** which should display all reservations for a room

      - Several **ReservationView** which should display the info about a reservation

It will be clearer with a drawing (ul.reservations is the place I want to render my ReservationsCollectionView views:

[image: the architecture]
In the **onRender** of RoomView, I tried to render the RoomCollectionView like this:

```
var RoomView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({      
    ui: {
        $reservationsList: 'ul.reservations',
        $noReservation: '.no-reservation',
      },

      onRender: function(){
        // Display reservations
        var reservationsCollection = this.model.get('reservations');
        var reservationsCollectionView = new ReservationsCollectionView(
            {collection:reservationsCollection}
        );
        //$('ul.reservations').html(reservationsCollectionView.render().el);
        this.ui.$reservationsList.html(reservationsCollectionView.render().el);

        if(reservationsCollection.length > 0)
        {
          this.ui.$noReservation.hide();
        }
        else
        {
          this.ui.$noReservation.show();
        }

        //$(this.ui.$reservationsList.el).html(reservationsCollectionView.render());
        //this.show(reservationsCollectionView);
      }
     //...
});
```

It works pretty well, but it renders the View in **ALL** the ul.reservations of the app, and not just for its RoomView...

Is it just a little problem or is it a larger architecture problem ? (I begin in Marionette...)

Thank you for your help

Comment: From docs: "You should provide a template attribute on the item view" - or I am reading you can set it to false, also in the docs they are specifying an `el` property (string selector) - I guess if you don't specify one it global searches?

Comment: Please show your `RoomsCollectionView` code